# Issue with addAll method

Tags: java

Whenever `Collection#addAll` is called, it creates a copy of the argument list and then attaches it to the collection on whom `addAll` was called.

Below is the code for case I :

```
        if (parentData != 0) {
            if (nodeParentMap.get(parentData) != null) {
                nodeParentMap.put(newNodeData, parentData);
                //Creates new Nodes' parent and assigns its next to its parent, in that way I get the parents' linked list
                Node parent = Node.build(parentData);
                parent.next = parentListMap.get(parentData);

                parentListMap.put(newNodeData, parent);
            }
        } else {
            //Code for root
            nodeParentMap.put(newNodeData, parentData);
            parentListMap.put(newNodeData, null);
        }
```

Here its takes `N` iterations to find `Nth parent`.

Below is the code for case II:

```
       if (parentData != 0) {
            if (nodeParentMap.get(parentData) != null) {
                nodeParentMap.put(newNodeData, parentData);

                //Here all the parents of a node are present in arrayList #parents, 
                //so that I can fetch parent in O(1) as I know the index
                ArrayList<Integer> parents = new ArrayList<>();
                parents.add(parentData);
                parents.addAll(parentListMap.get(parentData));

                parentListMap.put(newNodeData, parents);
            }
        } else {
            //Code for root
            nodeParentMap.put(newNodeData, parentData);
            parentListMap.put(newNodeData, new ArrayList<>());
        }
```

But in case II when ArrayList#addAll is called, it creates copy of the list passed and then attatches it. So, Is there a way to execute `ArrayList#addAll` with calling `System#arrayCopy`?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think `addAll` creates a copy of the argument list?

Comment: @Mureinik In Oracle's JDK, it really does. The ArrayList's implementation first converts the given collection to an array, and then appends the array elements into its own internal storage.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not care. The difference will be unnoticeable unless you run this code millions of times. You should write your code as cleanly as possible, if possible, and make it show your intent. Do you have a performance issue? Have you profiled your code and the profiler showed you that you're spending a lot of time in copying the array elements?

Measure, don't guess. You need a way to tell there is an issue. And you need a way to tell whether it is gone after a code change.

Could you perhaps change your algorithm if there's so much duplicate data and so much element copying that you maybe could use a more efficient structure or algorithm? For example, you could use [`Iterables.concat()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) of Google Guava. The resulting code will be shorter, states your intent very cleanly and does not copy anything - the underlying `List` will contain a reference to the original data structure and will only get it lazily. Beware that if this is massively chained, you didn't actually help yourself...

If after all this you still think you need to avoid the double array copy anyway, what stops you from doing this?

```
List<Integer> tempParents = parentListMap.get(parentData);
List<Integer> parents = new ArrayList<>(tempParents.size() + 1);
parents.add(parentData);
for (Integer i : tempParents) {
    parents.add(i);
}
```

Note that performance-wise, **this code will generally be comparable to just calling `addAll()`** since in the ArrayList's overridden implementation of `addAll()` there's no iteration, just hard array copying which is intrinsified in the JVM and highly optimized. The above version will therefore only be useful for short lists (probably) or to solve a memory issue, not a performance one as the iterative version does not require any extra temporary memory while the copying one from `addAll()` does.